# PHP and React.js - Best way to store a <svg> element. And read/return/fetch for both languages

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, svg

### Background information##

I'm working on a Wordpress Gutenberg project. And as you might know, Gutenberg uses React on the backend. But PHP on the frontend. (if can't store it pre-rendered.)

First I stored the `<svg>` HTML elements inside the post content. But after 3 SVG images, it gets too big to store for MySQL. So, now I can't store the Post pre-rendered in the backend I just have to get it dynamically each page load with PHP.

### The question

Moving on the question itself. Is there a way to store an HTML `<svg>` element (with CSS animations) to an external file that both React and PHP can load/fetch?

### Thoughts

- at first (with react) I had stored it in a `.jsx`filetype. Exported it as a const returning a multi-line string.
- I thought of placing it within a `.JSON` filetype. But then I would have to `JSON.stringify()` it first to escape the characters. But that would result in a human unfriendly way to edit it.
- Saving it an SVG won't help, since it's animated.
- I could translate all JSX constants containing all the svgs to a PHP function. But that would make it less flexible if I decide to go back to React.

Any help or pointers are very welcome